# Can I transfer registrar and owner email in the same auth code?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar

I have one `.com` domain name that's created and owned by a company we hired 5 years back. Now I decided to take things under my control so I asked the company to transfer the domain ownership to me. The company provided me the auth code for the domain. However, the domain name will expire on 29-01-2020 and there's not enough time to change the ownership and transfer the registrar since there are ICANN 60 days rule.

Is it possible to transfer both the registrar and domain ownership at the same time?

Comment: Change the domain owner (registrant) _before_ the domain is transferred? (Aside: It sounds like the company "you hired 5 years ago" shouldn't have set themselves as the owner (ie. the legal registrant) in the first place?!)

Comment: No, can I do the transfer and then change contact information in one go? To answer your comment. That company put the owner's name as the owner of the domain but at that time, I guess the owner doesn't have an email address yet. so the company uses their own email.

Comment: "...and owner _email_" - The "owner/registrant email" should ideally be accessible prior to initiating the domain transfer since a request to transfer the domain will be sent to that email address. This is important for a "quick" transfer, however, this will likely timeout after 5+ days anyway if the confirmation email has not been responded to and the domain will transfer anyway.

Comment: "if the confirmation email has not been responded to and the domain will transfer anyway" In standard gTLD with ICANN rules, there should be FOAs (less true nowadays with the current - broken - state of whois) and positive reply to an FOA (sent by email) is required to start the transfer, without it the new registrar is not even allowed to start the transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ICANN 60 days rule.

Well it's not apply in your case, since the domain is already register 5 year ago (not 60 days ago), and I've assume you've not change any detail from last 60 days.

Domain transfer is really easy nowadays, it doesn't require time at all, you can transfer any domain name in only one day, or max two days. Also you can change anything you want with valid details.

First you need authcode, which you already got (your company might have first disable the protection and then request for authcode)

Now the procedure are different from one registrar to another registrar, because if you're in same registrar then ask for their help, they might transfer the ownership within their network so easily, but if you want to transfer your domain name from one registrar company to another, then you need some extra work.

1. Make sure your domain is not protected with who is protection, so disable the privacy of your domain first, and make sure it show valid email address.
2. Go to the any registrar and follow the procedure to transfer, there make sure you enter the valid new details. Here you're fully allowed to change anything you want including name, email, business address, phone etc.
3. That new domain registrar will look for who is information and send the confirmation  link to the old email address(which might accessible to only your company which you've hired in past, so talk with them and say please confirm the approval).
4. Your new regisrar now have power to control your domain name, but first it should be release from your old domain name. Again to release the domain name from your old registrar **quickly** there are some procedure, so simple follow their FAQ about how to release the domain name or approve the release of domain name quickly. [For godaddy you can reference this article](https://in.godaddy.com/help/accept-or-decline-a-transfer-away-from-godaddy-6040). Once you do that step, simply ask your new regisrar to speed up the process, they will do it, since you're new customer for them.

If you follow 4th step cleverly you can easily transfer any domain name to any registrar within one or two day, otherwise your old domain registrar will wait for 5 to 7 days, and if they don't receive any complaint about that transfer, then they will approve the transfer of domain name automatically.

Comment: "Well it's not apply in your case" - Although the OP has expressed a requirement to also change the owner. This will need to be done _before_ the transfer or wait 60+ days after the domain transfer. (?)

Comment: "This will need to be done before the transfer or wait 60+ days after the domain transfer" That should be done at the time of transfer, which I already said in step no.2 .

Comment: "you can transfer any domain name in only one day, or max two days." Reference for that? Standard gTLD transfers are auto-approved by registries after 5 days if current registrar does nothing. So it can last up to 5 days. Even more in other TLDs (like 8 or 22 days in .FR for example)

Comment: I've done that, and it's my personal experience. Please refer my step no.4. I already said if you contact your old domain registrar then they might give you some steps to release the domain name ASAP, I've already given example of godaddy to transfer out. By doing that you just need to contact the new domain registrar and they will fully transfer the domain in one day only. Again it's my personal experience with godaddy, namecheap, porkbun and google domains.

Comment: To update, it turned out that if you have the auth code, you can do a transfer, and you could also update your information at the same time as long as the previous owner approves it. I was under the impression that you can't change the owner's email while transferring because the data wouldn't match but it turned out to not be the case.